# Sync issues Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 on MS Exchange mail account

Tags: sync, email, exchange, samsung-galaxy-tab-10

My MS Echange mail sync won't work properly on my Samsung 10.1 Tab.

It shows two flaws - whatever I try:

1. INBOX Mail sync is simply not complete.
   On Push, Manual or Timed delivery I will nog get all my mail in.
2. In my INBOX a lot of "empty mails" appear, dated 1-1-1970, the beginning
   of computer time. I simply delete them, but since they do not appear in my
   corporate email account or on the phone, they must be due to sync errors.

Interesting background input is that I also have a Samsung Galaxy SII Phone, looking at the same mailserver and account and this perfectly gets all email in on the Phone. It looks at the same Exchange sever using the same details in settings. So it obviously can't have anything to do with Exchange, but is has to do something with the Galaxy Tab.
Or am I very wrong?

The tabmodel is GT-P7500, Android 3.2, kernel 2.6.36.3
The phone model is GT-I9100, Android 2.3.4, kernel 2.6.35.7.

Please help - I'm getting no response from Samsung and can't find a clue on the net yet.
Thanx in advance!! Rob.

Answer (score 1):

It maybye does make any sense but firmware update buildnummmer htj85b p7510xwkl1, fixes this problem on Android 3.2. Because we are based in The Netherlands and the original question also originated from here, i think a localization problem????

Answer (score 0):

You must update the firmware of the Galaxy Tab. We had the same problem on a tab with Android 3.2, but not on one with 3.1. After we did the firmware update the problem was fixed.

Dré

Comment: Did you get 3.1 and 3.2 backwards here?  Otherwise updating doesn't make much sense.